# Ruler in mobile/desktop device types show different height (Google Chrome browser)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Click "Toggle device toolbar"
2. Click "Device Type" on a panel (or firstly click "Add device type" via "More options")
3. Choose type "Mobile"
4. See element size on the height ruler and on the tooltip which appers if element is hovered - they are the same
5. Choose type "Desktop"
6. See element size on the height ruler and on the tooltip which appers if element is hovered - they are different

OS: Ubuntu 22/04
Browser: Google Chrome
Version: 114.0.5735.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I expect no differences in "Desktop" device type between height in tooltip (which appear if it is hovered) and at the height ruler

Additional context:
At screenshot ("desktop device type is selected") you can see the difference: tooltip shows a height of 860px, but ruler shows a height of a bit more than 700px

[mobile device type is selected](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/fuaucaqBAwWMeQ)
[desktop device type is selected](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/w-TMy4t8RxtvHQ)